# Why is the name of an object type different from the name of the class it belongs to?

Tags: r, oop

I am currently reading Chapter 9 in [Chambers' *Software for Data Analysis*](http://amzn.com/0387759352), and on page 337, he says:

> In contrast, there are some inherent restrictions on the classe in the
>   `contains=` argument. Classes supplied here must be either:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. One of the basic R object types, but not those types that are references or nonstandard; for example, not `"environment"` **or
>      `"symbol"` (the object type for class `"name"`)**.

where the emphasis is mine.

My naive question is, why is the name of the object type (`symbol`) different from the class name (`name`)? This clashes with my understanding of an object as an instance of a class. Are there any other such examples, and how should I think about the naming convention here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four letter sequence n-a-m-e really has two distinct meanings in R. (And do remember that R has been trying to *not* modify S syntax very much for 20+ years now. And remember that S was constructed in the same era as C and UNIX, so it may have pre-dated all the OOP and "regularization" clamor.) That design choice may preventing you from constructing or requiring another level of indirection. The interpreter can assumed to be able to handle predefined object types in the 'contains' specification but not to be able to handle types that are more flexible or would require looking up what was in the value that was passed to it. A "symbol" is an entry in a lookup table, i.e. a way of finding something rather than the "something" itself.

R has both "storage modes" and "types" in addition to "modes" and "classes":

```
> x=as.name('y')
> x
y
> mode(x)
[1] "name"
> class(x)
[1] "name"

> typeof(x)
[1] "symbol"
> storage.mode(x)
[1] "symbol"
```

Comment: Thanks, though that was not my question. The quote was just to place my doubt in situ. I am wondering why the object and the class don't have the same name.

Comment: Maybe reading `?typeof` will help. (And the object and the class would never be the same. The class is an attribute of the object.)

Comment: If defined in the standard OOP sense, then the object type and class _should_ be the same. However, I guess object type means something specific in R parlance, wrt to the C storage and implementation.

Comment: R is NOT a "standard OOP" language.

Comment: As per our email exchanges, I am not entirely convinced that there is good reason behind the terminology ;) but am marking this as correct.