# R: S3 has no encapsulation (and other questions)

Tags: c++, r, oop

I have [struggled with this in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762559/why-is-the-name-of-an-object-type-different-from-the-name-of-the-class-it-belong), and I am still trying to get my head around what OOP *really* means in an R context. I have some specific questions based on [this](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/03/using-closures-as-objects-in-r/) Win-Vector blog post, about S3 classes/methods specifically.

It appears to me that in R, the structure containing the data, the name of the class, and the methods that are applicable for that class are all different things, and in the S3 model, tacked together for convenience.

1. (**Class names & objects**) A class attribute of an R object is a regular character attribute, and any class can be attributed to any object, regardless of contents or even content slots. AFAIK, this would not be allowed in classic OOP languages such as C++ or Java (what exactly is the mechanism stopping this in C++?). The object has to conform to the structure defined at the time of class definition for it to have the class name.
   **What are the implications of this separation of class name and object structure?**

   ```
   str1 = structure(list(slot1 = "a", slot2 = "b"))  
   class(str1) = "myclass"  
   class(str1) = "some_exotic_class"
   ```
2. (**Inheritance**) There is one more level of disjointedness when we get to the methods that apply to any given class. Inheritance is not deduced, but the object needs to explicitly have the class names to be apply the methods corresponding to that class.

   ```
   add = function(...) UseMethod("add")
   add.list = function(somelist) {
     Reduce(paste0, somelist)
   }
   str1 = structure(list(slot1 = "a", slot2 = "b"))
   add(str1)
   str2 = structure(list(slot1 = "a", slot2 = "b"), class = "mystr")
   add(str2)   # this will fail even though the contents are identical str1
   ```
3. (**Encapsulation**) What does lack of encapsulation mean here? Does it mean that there are no data members of the R object (and by extension an S3 class, which is just a plain old R object with a class attribute) which can be hidden from the action of methods? Or is there something more to it?  This is true in Python as well where there are no private data members, and information hiding is implemented by name obfuscation.
4. (**Mutability**) What does it mean to say that objects are immutable? Does it mean that object fields cannot be changed in place without re-assigning the object?  Is this related to no-side effects? How is it imposed in the language model?

   ```
   str3 = structure(list(1, 2, 3), class = "my_number_class")
   incrementOne = function(...) UseMethod("incrementOne")
   incrementOne.my_number_class = function(somelist) lapply(somelist, function(x) x+1)
   incrementOne(str3)
   str3  # the values of str3 have not changed *in situ*
   ```

   I guess mutability would mean that the function `incrementOne` would have changed the values of the list items by one in place. However, the blog post goes on to say that *there are* some mutable objects in R. What are they?
5. (**S3 classes or methods?**) Is there such a thing as an S3 class? Or should we always be talking about S3 methods?

Happy to take directions to reading material here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This question is way too broad. A good Stack Overflow post has one clear, specific question that can be clearly answered. It would be daunting for one person to attempt to answer everyone of your questions on this case.

Comment: I see this as an accurate description of S3, posed rhetorically